# Docker image: Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

Here is `docker-componse.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mycars-mongo-container
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: r00tp455w0rd
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

here is `mongo-init.js`

```
print('Database setup start...');
db = db.getSiblingDB('mycars');
db.createUser({
  user: 'db_user_mycars',
  pwd: 'Mycars.123M',
  roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'Mycars' }],
});
db.createCollection('users');
db.createCollection('vehicles');

print('Database setup end.');
```

When I run a container using `docker-compose up` a container runs and I can connect to `mycars` db using `db_user_mycars` and life is good!

when I commit the container and create an image using `docker commit [container name] [image name]` it creates the image fine.

Now when I kill my running container and create a new one from the image I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f2db1931d06e1e46ba27842c780059f7dc936252cbd23cc02260c9b2d295ce4/merged/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js
```

any idea why that might be? What I want to achieve is I want to put this image on AWS ECR and whenever a container is created I want the `db_user_mycars` be created in that container.

Comment: It seems like you should be solving this with a `Dockerfile` and a `COPY` statement (and letting the initialization happen at runtime).

Comment: Thanks @larsks Can you please decrypt the comment above lol. I am new to docker world.

Comment: Some of the [intro documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) on Docker addresses this process, with examples. I would start there, but there are a variety of other docker tutorials online that will help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't run `docker commit` you won't have this problem.

The container you're running has three things in it: the code and base OS from the `mongo` image; the database data in a hidden anonymous volume; and the config file you're bind-mounting.  If you `docker-compose down` this container and `docker-compose up` to bring it up again, you will get a basically identical container.

This is normal Docker behavior: you should always be able to delete and recreate a container and not lose state, possibly requiring you to mount some sort of storage for persistent state.  **You should never run `docker commit`.**  This gets you a "golden" image that you can't easily recreate or update.  And to retiterate, in this state where you're running a Docker Hub image with mounted configuration, there's no particular need to.

Probably what's actually happening here is that Docker needs to make some change in the container filesystem to record that a file will be mounted in `mongo-init.js` (normally Linux filesystem mounts are directories).  When you commit the container and try to relaunch it, it has some sort of record that *something* should be mounted there, and the actual volume mount conflicts with it.

You only have this problem because you're running `docker commit`.  If you don't `docker commit`, you can run your setup reproducibly with your config file mounted into the unmodified `mongo` image.

Comment: The reason why I need to run `docker commit` and get the image is I want to push it to AWS container registry and fron there I want to create a container in AWS.

Comment: You can run the Docker Hub image out of AWS too.  If you need a custom image, then write a Dockerfile and check it into source control, and have your CI system push the image to ECR, but that's not necessary for what you show here.